# AD custom attribute New-ADUser powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My problem is that i don't know how to address my custom Attributes in AD Powershell

I normally user something like this

```
New-ADUser -Name "Test" -surname "User" -description "User Description"
```

However when i try to set a value to my custom attribute such as

```
New-ADUser -Name "Test" -surname "User" -description "User Description" -reportingManagerID "012345"
```

I receive this error:

```
New-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'reportingManagerID'.
At line:1 char:247
+ ... " -StreetAddress "address" -Surname "User" -reportingManagerID "1234"
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `-OtherAttributes` parameter.

Quoting directly from the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/new-aduser?view=winserver2012-ps

> To set the value of a custom attribute called favColors that takes a set of Unicode strings, use the following syntax:

```
-OtherAttributes @{'favColors'="pink","purple"}
```

> To set values for favColors and dateOfBirth simultaneously, use the following syntax:

```
-OtherAttributes @{'favColors'="pink","purple"; 'dateOfBirth'=" 01/01/1960"}
```